# datastructure, two threads in javascript reading and writing on same object

Tags: javascript, algorithm, asynchronous

The language is javascript, but i think this question is language agnostic. Here is the problem:

**Problem**

Two waiters servicing the table. One is cleaning and one is putting new dishes out. The busboy has to make sure he does not put away freshly put dishes. A requirement exists that the busboy and the server perform their task in small units of work AND to make it look to the customer that their food is being served quickly, the server HAS to work at the same time as the busboy. This is a low-end buffet, so the dishes finished/taken away could be brought again (more pancakes anyone?)

**Steps:**

1. busboy comes, picks up 5 dishes out of 15 on the table, takes them to the kitchen.
2. server comes lays down 5 new dishes out of 35 on his order sheet. Couple dishes (pancakes and blueberries) are the same kind as what was just taken away, and the rest are new ones.
3. This continues until both busboy and server are done. Bust boy has 15 plates to take care of in 3 go's. Server has 35 dishes to bring in 7 go's.
4. what's left on the table afterwards 35 plates.

**Restrictions:**

- Servers have to work in a direction closest-to-customer-first.
- Bust boy has to make sure he does not take those 2 fresh plates of pancakes and blueberries away, which could happen if he comes in to clean them up AFTER server lays down fresh ones - right on top of old ones.

In javascript I have a setInterval(bust, 50) function that cleans up the UI, and a setInterval(serve, 50) that adds new elements to the UI. Two simulated threads are working at the same time because to clean up in serial sequence would take 10 seconds and to serve it may take another 20 seconds. Instead I would like to make it appear that progress is being made - especially in the visible area. The above mentioned plates are really html id's and DOM is being manipulated. I keep an array/hashtable of the items I am manipulating.

What's my algorithm?

EDIT:
I remember in graphics, you typically would paint to a hidden buffer and then toggle visible buffer with hidden buffer. I don't know how to apply this concept to my problem. These are thousands of dom elements, not pixels. Removing elements, trashing them and adding new ones could be costly.

Comment: meh, been a while since i've seen a js question that wasn't "here's a hundred lines of code, find the bug"

Comment: You can start by posting a jsFiddle with what you've got.

Comment: could you please post some of the code you are using?

Comment: Note that javascript is single process, single thread.. all the time. Unless you use webworkers, but in that case you still won't have a shared state.

Comment: He is simulating multi threading with the setInterval I'm assuming.

Comment: `setInterval` is not a good solution because of the non-multithreaded nature of JS. See here for an explanation: http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#other.timeouts

Comment: @Asad it's a 2,000 line JS i am optimizing (can't share on jsfiddle).

Comment: why on earth are you doing this is javascript?

Comment: @Asad it's browser executed code, it manipulates the DOM taken the user input (alternating css classes on DOM elements, hiding some, showing others, etc). Problem is not language specific I thought.

Comment: Some languages are multi threaded, some require hacks like setInterval, which is why js is not the best fit for this problem. Your problem is abstract, it is not tied to DOM elements, so why pick js?

Comment: @asad I tried to abstract the problem to capture wider audience, theorists, logic, math, data structure, puzzle solvers. The actual problem I am solving is in existing code executing on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a typical capacitated vehicle routing problem. In this problem you have a warehouse, containers and trucks and want to find the shortest route to serve the containers but you are limited to carry x containers per truck. It's a combination of bin-packing problem and travel salesman problem. I think you can replace the warehouse with the kitchen and the trucks with the waiters and the containers with the dishes.

Comment: Ok, I'll brush up on all of those. Thanks Chiyou.